# GoCD Agent how to run command on different folder (outside of agent working directory)

Tags: linux, cicd, go-cd, go-agent

In my "deploy" pipeline, I have pulled the built artifact from upstream pipeline, but the problem is my working directory is different compared to the GoCD Agent working directory, so I can't deploy that artifact to my working dir. Additionally, I must run some command on my working dir after moving the artifact, e.g. `npm run production`.

- My working dir: `/var/www/vhosts/project`
- GoCD Agent working dir: `/var/lib/go-agent`

So, how can I copy the artifact to the outside of GoCD Agent and then run some additional commands?

Thanks a lot.